# Display if statement variable in messagebox

Tags: c#, variables

I'm having issues with displaying the variable within a Message box. What I want to do is display in a messagebox which Combobox hasn't been filled in, it will display this in a list within the messagebox and then stop the user from saving to the database. The error is stating that it is a use of an unassigned variable but I have assigned it at the top of the 'if' statement.

```
private void btnSaveDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbPolType.SelectedItem == null || 
            cmbPolNum.SelectedItem == null ||
            cmbTPReg.SelectedItem == null || 
            cmbLossType.SelectedItem == null || 
            cmbLossDesc.SelectedItem == null ||
            cmbInsdFault.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            string polType, polNum, lossType, lossDesc, tpReg, insdFault = null;

            if (cmbPolType.SelectedItem==null)
            {
                polType = "Policy Type";
            }

            if (cmbPolNum.SelectedItem==null)
            {
                 polNum = "Policy Number";
            }
            if (cmbLossType.SelectedItem==null)
            {
                lossType = "Loss Type";
            }
            if (cmbLossDesc.SelectedItem ==null)
            {
                lossDesc = "Loss Description";
            }
            if (cmbTPReg.SelectedItem==null)
            {
                tpReg = "TP Reg";
            }
            if (cmbInsdFault.SelectedItem==null)
            {
                insdFault = "Insd at Fault";
            }

            MessageBox.Show("You have not selected options for the following: " + lossDesc );
        }
```

Comment: You have `insdFault` assigned to `null`, but `lossDesc` only declared. Multiple variable declaration and definition doesn't work like that.

Comment: Just another quick note, if you're wanting to print out which options are at fault, you may want to use a StringBuilder then append to it in each if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No *lossDesc* is not initialized in that way as well as the other strings variables but the *insdFault*. (The error message points to *lossDesc* because is the only one used in the remainder of the code).

Instead of initializing each one, I suggest to use a simple `List<string>` where you add your error messages and type all of them at the end of the test

```
List<string> missingData = new List<string>();
if (cmbPolType.SelectedItem == null)
    missingData.Add("Policy Type");
if (cmbPolNum.SelectedItem == null)
    missingData.Add("Policy Number");
if (cmbLossType.SelectedItem == null)
    missingData.Add("Loss Type");
if (cmbLossDesc.SelectedItem == null)
    missingData.Add("Loss Description");
if (cmbTPReg.SelectedItem == null)
    missingData.Add("TP Reg");
if (cmbInsdFault.SelectedItem == null)
    missingData.Add("Insd at Fault");

if(missingData.Count > 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("You have not selected options for the following: " + 
                    Environment.NewLine + 
                    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, missingData.ToArray()));
}
else
{

   ... save to database ? ....
}
```

This removes the need to use and initialize a bunch of string variables and uses the `string.Join` method to get the whole error message in a single string with each error on a separate line.

Comment: This approach is good. It allows for easy adding of extra validation.

Comment: Yes, @stefchri I would also remove that ugly if statement at the beginning because adds only another point of possible errors in case of new combos to check and the gain (if any) is minimal.

Comment: Many thanks for all of your prompt replies. The list is a much better way to proceed with..Thank you !